# Active character only in text mode

Tags: math-mode, text-mode, active-characters

I have the following code to replace `'` to `\textquotesingle`, because I prefer this symbol when I type an apostrophe.

```
\makeatletter
\catcode`\'=\active
\def'{\textquotesingle}
\makeatother
```

The problem is that when I want to write a derivate of a function it doesn't compile, I have to type `\text{'}`, but it doesn't even look good, it should look a bit slanted.

So I was wondering if is it posible to only make `'` an active character in text mode and not in math mode, so I can easily type `\[ f'(x) \]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to differentiate between text and math mode, but also to update the internal macro that looks forward for another `'` in math mode to take care of the new category code.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\catcode`\'=\active
\protected\def'{\ifmmode\expandafter\active@math@prime\else\textquotesingle\fi}
\gdef\pr@m@s{%
  \ifx'\@let@token
    \expandafter\pr@@@s
  \else
    \ifx^\@let@token
      \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\pr@@@t
    \else
      \egroup
    \fi
  \fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

It's $f'$ or $f''$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I already accepted the answer but I just found out that using `titletoc` there's a bug. In the table of contents if a subsection has a `'` there is an error of missing $, and since the `'` character the text is in italic (like in math mode). Any ideas?

Comment: Update!! I just removed `\protected` and so far I can say it works perfectly (so far). Thank you anyways for your answer.